# How to print ALL columns of MySQL table in Python?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, python-2.7, dataframe, mysql-python

Here I want to print every column present in the MySQL table **(PASSENGER)**, but this code only gives 4-5 columns.

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector as myq
d = myq.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="admin", database="air")
df = pd.read_sql("select * from Passengers", d)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      Ticket_Number       Date   Passenger  ...        Class       Stat Announcement
0              1          1              1  ...            1          1            1
1         184784          1              1  ...            1          1            1
2         184785          1              1  ...            1          1         None
3         184787  9:12:2020     Jeet        ...  FIRST CLASS  CONFIRMED         None
4         184789  9:12:2020     Jeet        ...  FIRST CLASS  CONFIRMED         None
5         184790  9:12:2021     Jeet        ...  FIRST CLASS  CONFIRMED         None
```

This is what Python is returning to my code. Here I want all 12 columns.

Desired output:

```
Ticket_Number   Date    Passenger      Flight_Code         Airline      Departs_From         Arrives_TO    Departs    Arrives      Class          Stat    Announcement 
        1        1          1               1                1                1                   1          1          1           1            1              1      
   184784        1          1               1                1                1                   1          1          1           1            1              1            
   184785        1          1               1                1                1                   1          1          1           1            1           none         
   184787  9:12:2020     Jeet           CX131    Cathay Pacific       London,UK     Ahemdabad,India   04:40:00   18:20:00  FIRST CLASS   CONFIRMED           none         
   184789  9:12:2020     Jeet           CX131    Cathay Pacific       London,UK     Ahemdabad,India   04:40:00   18:20:00  FIRST CLASS   CONFIRMED           none         
   184790  9:12:2021     Jeet           QF248    Quantas              London,UK     Ahemdabad,India   23:50:00   13:50:00  FIRST CLASS   CONFIRMED           none
```

Comment: pass chunksize; i think default is 5

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass chunksize

```
df=pd.read_sql("select * from Passengers",d, chunksize=100)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/io.html#querying

Note: This will return a Iterator[Dataframe] you can use this iterator to fetch data in chunks of 100 rows